# How can we customize the player of a video shot with iframe?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, iframe

One I want to add a video from a website to my application using the iframe method, but I only want to add the video and I will design the player of the video myself. My question is, how can I add only the video to my application with iframe? Or how can I add the video with the player and then customize the player in my application? I know basic Python and JavaScript and use these two languages ​​in my application.